# sqlobject sqlmeta with composite key

Tags: python, primary-key, sqlobject

I have created my sqlobject class like so and set the primary key to **prm_id**

```
import sqlobject
from connection import conn
class tbl_episodes(sqlobject.SQLObject):
        class sqlmeta:
              idName = "prm_id"
        _connection = conn
        prm_id = sqlobject.IntCol(length=30)
        showid = sqlobject.IntCol(length=30, default=None)
        show_index = sqlobject.IntCol(length=30)
        videoid = sqlobject.IntCol(length=30)
```

However i have removed the primary key and decided to make **showid** and **show_index** as the composite primary key

how should i adjust my class to reflect the database change ?

Answer (score 0):

SQLObject doesn't support composite primary keys. SQLObject requires that every table has a primary key and the key must be a single column.

Generic SQL theory recommends having simple unique autoincremented int as the primary key.